# Python - Print index of for loop only once every five minutes

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, numbers

I'm trying to get a for loop to print the value of 'i' every 5 minutes

```
import threading
def f(i):
     print(i)
     threading.Timer(600, f).start()

for i in range(1,1000000000000):
    f(i=i)
```

However, this method results in the code printing the value of i instantly since it calls 'f' as soon as it finds 'i'.

I know this is not the first time someone will ask, nor the last, but I can't get it to work on a for loop nested within a function.

I'm fairly new to Python and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have something against the `sleep` function?

Comment: A sleep function in a loop would make everything halt, I want it to only occasionally print to the screen without slowing the process down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just keeping track of how long has passed in the loop?

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()

freq = 5 * 60       # Time in seconds
last_time = 0.0
for i in range(int(1e8)):
    ctime = timer()
    if ctime - last_time > freq:
        print(i)
        last_time = ctime
```

I imagine you can make this more efficient by only checking the time every N iterations rather than every time. You may also want to look into using [`progressbar2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2) for a ready-made solution.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html%20datetime), as I think it's more intuitive and looks a bit cleaner. Otherwise, using more or less the same approach as Paul:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

print_interval = timedelta(minutes=5)

# Initialize the next print time. Using now() will print the first
# iteration and then every interval. To avoid printing the first
# time, just add print_interval here (i.e. uncomment).
next_print = datetime.now() # + print_interval

for i in range(int(1e8)):
    now = datetime.now()
    if now >= next_print:
        next_print = now + print_interval
        print(i)
```

Also note that before python 3.x [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange%20xrange) would be preferable over `range`.